# Ocaml user-defined type pattern matching

Tags: ocaml

Here is my type definition:

```
type ('type1, 'type2) symbol =
  | N of 'type1
  | T of 'type2
```

Here are some types:

```
type mysub =| Abc | Bcd | Def
```

I also have a list `[N Abc;N Bcd; T"("]`.

What I want to do is that throw away all items of type `T`, and also throw away `'type1` or `'type2`. So the desired result is `[Abc; Bcd]`

But when I try this piece of code:

```
List.map (fun x-> match x with N (a)->a |T (b) ->b ) (List.filter (fun x->match x with
N (type1) ->true |T (type2) -> false) [N Abc;N Bcd; T"("]);;
```

it gives me the following message:

```
Error: This expression has type (mysub, string) symbol list
       but an expression was expected of type
         (mysub, mysub) symbol list
       Type string is not compatible with type mysub.
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this fragment

```
List.map
    (fun x -> match x with
    N a -> a
    T b -> b
    )
```

The return types aren't the same for the two match cases. If there were any `T b` elements in the list, the `b` would be a string, and the compiler doesn't know there aren't any such elements. Since you know there aren't any, you could fix this by supplying something other than `b` as the result for that case. Something like this:

```
List.map
    (fun x -> match x with
    N a -> a
    T _ -> Abc
    )
```

Or even this:

```
List.map
    (fun x -> match x with
    N a -> a
    T _ -> failwith "This can't happen"
    )
```

Comment: This is a bandaid. The proper solution is to not use a composition of map and filter, but a richer version, for instance `filter_map` (`('a -> 'b option) -> 'a list -> 'b list`) or flatmap.